# Dropdown2 data from REST call initiated by Dropdown1 does not load in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have 2 dropdown's! The first one has static data which has ng-change directive that calls a service method. This method calls a REST API, gets data passes it on to the controller where it sets the value of a certain array from response to a variable in scope.(like $scope.secondDropDownData= valueFromJSON).

I am using the secondDropDownData to load the second dropdown data. In the logs i see the data is received from REST call, but it does not load in the dropdown.

Below is the code i am using :

```
<div ng-app="appName" ng-init="loading=true; angularLoaded=true">

<div class="container" ng-controller="controller1">

<div class="row" id="exSelects">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4>Dropdown1</h4>
        <select id="x" ng-model="modelVal" ng-change="getSecondDropDown(inputVal)"  class="form-control">
            <option ng-repeat="x in xyz">{{x}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!--/col-->

    <div class="row" id="exSelects">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h4>Dropdown2</h4>
            <select ng-model="dropdwn2" class="form-control">
               <option ng-repeat="a in abc" value="{{a.id}}">{{a.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/row-->
</div>
```

Comment: Plunker or jsfiddle will be better

Comment: Solved this issue for now. Would use them next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. It was happening because i was using rootscope for the controller method that calls the REST service and gets the data, but used scope to set the value.

Now i am using same scope to declare the controller method and also set the variable i am using in second dropdown.